# -ms-flexbox e flexbox não funcionam no Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Estou com dificuldades para identificar o que devo fazer para consertar esse erro - Usei recentemente o [CSS Progress Wizard](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/responsive-step-progress-indicator-with-pure-css/), ele funciona perfeitamente no google chrome e outros navegadores:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando visualizo no **internet explorer 9**, ele apresenta alguns erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código do `CSS Progress Wizard`:

https://jsfiddle.net/cxj5r83v/

```
.flexer, .progress-indicator {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

    .no-flexer, .progress-indicator.stacked {
        display: block;
    }

.no-flexer-element {
    -ms-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0;
    -moz-flex: 0;
    flex: 0;
}

.flexer-element, .progress-indicator > li {
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.progress-indicator {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

    .progress-indicator > li {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        width: auto;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        color: #bbbbbb;
        display: block;
    }

        .progress-indicator > li:hover {
            color: #6e6e6e;
        }

        .progress-indicator > li .bubble {
            border-radius: 1000px;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #bbbbbb;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #888888;
        }

            .progress-indicator > li .bubble:before, .progress-indicator > li .bubble:after {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 9px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 3px;
                content: '';
                background-color: #bbbbbb;
            }

            .progress-indicator > li .bubble:before {
                left: 0;
            }

            .progress-indicator > li .bubble:after {
                right: 0;
            }

        .progress-indicator > li.completed {
            color: green;
        }

            .progress-indicator > li.completed .bubble {
                background-color: #65d074;
                color: #65d074;
                border-color: #247830;
            }

                .progress-indicator > li.completed .bubble:before, .progress-indicator > li.completed .bubble:after {
                    background-color: #65d074;
                    border-color: #247830;
                }

        .progress-indicator > li a:hover .bubble {
            background-color: #5671d0;
            color: #5671d0;
            border-color: #1f306e;
        }

            .progress-indicator > li a:hover .bubble:before, .progress-indicator > li a:hover .bubble:after {
                background-color: #5671d0;
                border-color: #1f306e;
            }

        .progress-indicator > li.danger .bubble {
            background-color: #d3140f;
            color: #d3140f;
            border-color: #440605;
        }

            .progress-indicator > li.danger .bubble:before, .progress-indicator > li.danger .bubble:after {
                background-color: #d3140f;
                border-color: #440605;
            }

        .progress-indicator > li.warning .bubble {
            background-color: #edb10a;
            color: #edb10a;
            border-color: #5a4304;
        }

            .progress-indicator > li.warning .bubble:before, .progress-indicator > li.warning .bubble:after {
                background-color: #edb10a;
                border-color: #5a4304;
            }

        .progress-indicator > li.info .bubble {
            background-color: #5b32d6;
            color: #5b32d6;
            border-color: #25135d;
        }

            .progress-indicator > li.info .bubble:before, .progress-indicator > li.info .bubble:after {
                background-color: #5b32d6;
                border-color: #25135d;
            }

    .progress-indicator.stacked > li {
        text-indent: -10px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }

        .progress-indicator.stacked > li .bubble:before, .progress-indicator.stacked > li .bubble:after {
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -1.5px;
            width: 3px;
            height: 100%;
        }

    .progress-indicator.stacked .stacked-text {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: 60% !important;
        width: 45% !important;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.2em;
    }

    .progress-indicator.stacked > li a {
        border: none;
    }

@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .progress-indicator {
        font-size: 60%;
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Abri no Internet Explorer 11**](http://i.imgur.com/z34kWmQ.jpg) e não tem problema nenhum. Qual versão está testando?

Comment: estranho, estou no IE9 @re22

Comment: Talvez um reset CSS resolva seu caso, como por exemplo o `normalize.css` http://www.tekzoom.com.br/reset-css-melhore-seu-codigo-cross-browser/[inserir a descrição do link aqui](http://www.tekzoom.com.br/reset-css-melhore-seu-codigo-cross-browser/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cara realmente o "flex" não funciona no IE 9, ele funciona um pouco no IE 10 e só a partir do 11 que realmente funciona. [Aqui](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) você pode ver os navegadores e as versões que suportam.

Aqui tem um exemplo de progresso *sem utilizar flex*, vê se te ajuda:

```css
.etapas {
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.etapas li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1%;
}
.etapas li.active:before, .etapas li.complete:before, .etapas li.active .etapa, .etapas li.complete .etapa {
  border-color: #5293c4;
}
.etapas li:first-child:before {
  max-width: 51%;
  left: 50%;
}
.etapas li:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 4px solid #ced1d6;
  position: relative;
  top: 21px;
  z-index: 1;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.etapas li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1%;
}
.etapas li.active .etapa, etapas li.complete .etapa {
  border-color: #5293c4;
}
.etapas li .etapa {
  border: 5px solid #ced1d6;
  color: #546474;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.etapas li.complete .titulo, .etapas li.active .titulo {
  color: #2b3d53;
}
.etapas li .titulo {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
  color: #949ea7;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 104;
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<ul class="etapas">
    <li class="active">
        <span class="etapa">1</span>
        <span class="titulo">Passo 1</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="etapa">2</span>
        <span class="titulo">Passo 2</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="etapa">3</span>
        <span class="titulo">Passo 3</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="etapa">4</span>
        <span class="titulo">Passo 4</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Vou marcar como certa por ser a resposta que apresenta uma solução sem usar o flex. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Existem três possíveis problemas

1. (acaso seja IE10 ou IE11) é que você não está usando o parâmetro de compatibilidade com o valor `Edge`, então adicione isto:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
   ```
2. Possivelmente você está usando uma versão do Internet Explorer 10 que veio antes do *release* de [Agosto de 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265027(v=vs.85).aspx) (talvez você esteja usando a versão "beta" ou pre-release), neste caso é necessário usar o Windows Update.
3. Você está usando uma versão mais antiga, versões anteriores ao [Internet Explorer 10 não suportam o `flex-box`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265027(v=vs.85).aspx).

   [Comentário do autor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69726/ms-flexbox-e-flexbox-n%C3%A3o-funcionam-no-internet-explorer/69766#comment142690_69726) confirma isto:

   > estranho, estou no IE9 @re22